# Error while connecting sql to php

Tags: php, mysql

I have written following line of code and it gives me error:

```
<?php

$host = "Localhost";
$user = "usr_shiv";
$pass = "abcdsva234On0";
$dbName = "db_shiv";
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbName);

if($con->connect_errno){
die("Error1 : ".$con->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO name (first, last)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}

$sql = "SELECT first, last FROM name";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "first: " . $row["first"]. " - last: " . $row["last"]."<br>";
}
} 
else {
echo "0 results";
}

$con->close();


?>
```

Error:

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'usr_shiv'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mihir\db.php on line 11
Error1 : Access denied for user 'usr_shiv'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: use $host='localhost'; instead of Localhost and check password is write or not ?

Comment: password is wrong or that user doesn't have permisson to that database

Comment: @BeingSunny Localhost works

Comment: @clearshot66 Password is correct and user have permission